# Can `data.table` be used safely instead of `dplyr` with `sparkR`, `sparklyr` and `rsparkling`?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I am refreshing my `H2O on Spark` knowledge using RStudio [Spark Extensions](https://spark.rstudio.com/guides/h2o/) as one of the sources.

Frankly everywhere I look, I find `dplyr`'s unnecessarily convoluted efforts in coming out with even simplest results quite painful if not opaque in most cases.

Here is an example taken from the site. The `mtcars` dataset has been copied into `Spark` cluster under the name `mtcars_tbl` then, while subseting/filtering it for cars with more than 100 hp,
the "tbl_spark", "tbl_sql", "tbl_lazy",  "tbl" - class table was
split in **train** and **test** subsets contained in a 2-component list.

The list name is 'partitions' and the `dplyr` code to achieve it is this:

```
 partitions <- mtcars_tbl %>% filter(hp >= 100) %>%
 mutate(cyl8 = cyl == 8) %>%
 sdf_partition(training = 0.5, test = 0.5, seed = 1099)
```

**Note**: In my opinion, `H2O` has a clearer, more informative way of doing this

Then, a model is trained within the `H2O` platform fitting 'mpg' for various car weight and cylinder configurations.

At some point - and for prediction purposes - there is a need to select (isolate) the column 'mpg' form the **test** subset and use it as numeric vector.

Here is the `dplyr` code implemented for an action as simple as this:

```
mpg1 <- partitions$test %>% 
                select(mpg) %>% 
                      collect() %>%
                           `[[`("mpg")
```

... and here is the `data.table` code clear, compact and simple applied to the "partitions" list:

```
mpg2 <- as.data.frame(partitions$test)[['mpg']]

mpg3 <- as.data.table(partitions$test)[['mpg']]
```

**Note**: The code would have been even more uncluttered had the two subsets been treated as `dataframe`s or `data.table`s from the beginning.

As of comparing the three vectors:

```
identical(mpg1, mpg2, mpg3)

TRUE

all.equal(mpg1, mpg2, mpg3)

TRUE
```

**Note**: the function `dplyr::collect()` shown above, actually changes the class of **mpg1** from

"tbl_spark" "tbl_sql" "tbl_lazy" "tbl"

to

"tbl_df" "tbl" "**data.frame**"

which, subsequently is turned into a numeric vector in the last step, namely `'[['('mpg')`.

Well, seemingly there are a number of superfluous steps in the `dplyr` code above. And this is just a simple case!

I wonder if `dplyr` could be safely circumvented for operations that take place within R hence, my question in the title.

**Note**: I know that one option is `SQL` query; is there any other (better) way?

Thank you!

Comment: You do not have to use the pipe with ```dplyr```. For example, you could use ```partitions$test[['mpg']]``` and it would extract the vector. However, as the question is related on whether it would work with the ```spark``` interface, I am unsure. But I am aware that ```dtplyr``` lazily collects to make more performant [tag:data.table] queries. I can only expect that ```sparklyr``` would also be most performant with idiomatic ```dplyr``` functional sequences (i.e., the pipe chains).

Comment: @ Cole: Thank you for your comment! I may have not made myself clear: it is not (only) the pipe operator that I find superfluous. Comments like "there is no data.table interface to Spark" are uninformative tacitly neglecting the fact that - as my example shows - the `dataframe` (`data.table` by extension) _is being_ used together with the base extractor `[[`. On another note, I am not sure your solution works as expected; I had tried it before posting and the result was "NULL". Maybe `[[` needs to dig dipper in this case (see `str(partitions$test)`)

Comment: It _is_ informative, it just doesn't lend itself to a solution. See also https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1828. And related, the ```dtplyr```method of ```as.data.table()``` collects and executes the query. Based on your findings, that may be true of the ```sparklyr```interface. Anyway, just as you seem frustrated from potentially patronizing comments, please reflect on your own comments. Note, you did not indicate the (subjective) reasons you disliked dplyr code, leaving others to speculate. And I say this as a data.table enthusiast.

Comment: @ Cole I thought I did indicate the reasons: unnecessary wrapping of R base code resulting in opaqueness: I like my code to say what it does however complex. Why the need for `mutate`, `transmute`, `collect` etc. when there had been already mathematical operations for all of that? Also code written this way is longer and mostly slower with large datasets. Not very troubleshooting-friendly either. And yes, I am as subjective as anyone else! I want to control the tools I use every time I read a tutorial. As of links: [check the table here](https://mgimond.github.io/rug_2019_12/Index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use `pull(partitions$test, mpg)`? Your approach is not the idiomatic `dplyr` way to do this operation, so it's no surprise that it's frustrating for you.

There is no `data.table` interface for Spark. You can use Spark SQL if you prefer that. `sparklyr` just generates Spark SQL under the hood.

You are certainly not obligated to use `dplyr` but I encourage you to familiarize yourself more with its syntax before discounting it completely -  there are likely much more concise ways of doing the stuff you find frustrating.

Comment: @ bcarlsen Thank you for reply! I wasn't looking for a patronizing lecture but for constructive ways to circumvent dplyr and not looking for the "idiomatic dplyr way" to operate. I was aware of SQL alternative and I am familiar with dplyr syntax.

Comment: I didn't intend to be patronizing. The alternative to using `dplyr` syntax in R is Spark SQL. There is no R translation layer for Spark that uses base or data.table syntax.

Comment: @ bcarlsed I did not say you intended to be patronizing!